# 'True' was used before it was defined

Tags: javascript, boolean

I have a JavaScript error that says: `'True' was used before it was defined`.
I have this code:

```js
var playAgain = window.confirm("Play again? OK for yes, Cancel for no.");
if (playAgain === True) {
    loop();
}
```

and I want to make it not have that error.

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive and `True` is not the same as `true`. Though in this case you could also completely omit the `=== true` part.

Comment: JS in not Python

`True` should be `true` _ Also, you don't need to `expression === true`... simply: `if (playAgain)` **is all you need**. Learn about `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`True` is a variable and it should be declared before use. But what you are expecting is `true` which a `data type` in javascript. Since JS is case-sensitive so `True` is not same as `true.`

replace `True` with `true`.

```js
const True = "I am a variable";
console.log(True);
```

You can't use `true` as a variable name.

```
const true = "Error";   // SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'true'
console.log(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript the correct writing for the boolean is `true`. If what you are trying to do is defining and using a variable named `True`, consider defining it (eg. `const True = true`).